# How to create custom pages in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to create a custom page in Marketing cloud such that they interact with a third party using the third party API.
How can I develop this page within Marketing cloud only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create whats called a CloudPage.  Refer to the following documentations.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_cloudpages.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

For interacting with 3rd party APIs, I will in addition to CloudPages - being the standard tool for web pages on Marketing Cloud, look into [SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.htm), which is more capable of interacting with APIs, parsing JSON etc, than AMPScript.

Comment: can SSJS interact with CloudPage and display or fetch the data from Cloud pages?

Comment: Yes, you can use SSJS in a context of CloudPages: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232465&type=1